# ASP.NET Core localization ignores default culture

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to enable localization on our main-project, but hidden as a beta-feature to be implemented but not yet usable.

In my `Startup.cs` -> `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` I've added:

```
// localization
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    // get the cultures from app-setting
    var supportedCultures = Configuration.GetSection(Constants.Configuration.Keys.Cultures).GetChildren().ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value).Keys.ToArray();

    // set what should be the default language
    options.SetDefaultCulture("fr-FR");

    // set cultures for api and ui
    options.AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures);
    options.AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});
```

where `supportedCultures` is read from the `appsettings.json` which looks this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Cultures": {
    "de-DE": "Deutsch",
    "en-US": "Englisch",
    "es-ES": "Español",
    "fi-FI": "Suomalainen",
    "fr-FR": "Français"
  }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, that, as soon as `de-DE` is part of the supported languages, `options.SetDefaultCulture("fr-FR")` is ignored totally.
If I comment out `"de-DE": "Deutsch",` in the `appsettings.json` the application corretctly uses my french translations. If not commented it always uses german.

My system is installed in english but has its keyboard and dates set to use german.

#### Update 1

Using

> app.UseRequestLocalization("fr-FR");

as described here [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#statically-set-the-culture) is working as expected but not the way I am using it.

#### Update 2

As of the first comments the questions seems to be why `app.UseRequestLocalization("fr-FR");` is working, but `app.UseRequestLocalization(options => ...);` is not.

Comment: From what I know this is the purpose of Localization, it will try to get the right culture depending on the user, the default culture is only used when the one used by user is not found, which seems to be `de-DE` in your case.

Comment: Since initially I 'missed' the 'blazor' tags, I have few questions. 1) Do you use cookie for the language, or query string? 2) If you use cookie, when you change the language (wherever you have a dropdown), do you redirect the page (refresh)?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine `app.UseRequestLocalization("fr-FR");` is doing what I want, no matter what I have in `appsettings.json` but the call `app.UseRequestLocalization(options => ...);` is not working

Comment: @Ergis Yes. Cookies and refresh when changing the language as described in the MSDocs

Comment: @KingKerosin SetDefaultCulture: Set the default culture which is used by the application when supported culture could not be determined by one of the configured IRequestCultureProviders. `de-DE` is found so it does not use the default culture. With `UseRequestLocalization("fr-FR")`, you statically assign the culture to `fr-FR`.

Comment: I had to remove AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider

`options.RequestCultureProviders.RemoveAt(2);`